# Why is this PDF javascript Date being incorrectly calculated only once a year?

Tags: javascript, date, pdf

I have an interesting result from the javascript in an Acrobat PDF Form

I have a series of date form fields. The first field is for user entry and the remaining fields are calculated by javascript, each field incremented by one day.

The code is:

```
var strStart = this.getField("userField").value; 

if(strStart.length > 0) {
  var dateStart = util.scand("dd/mm/yy",strStart);
  var dateStartMilli = dateStart.getTime();
  var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1;  // number of milliseconds in one day
  var dateMilli = dateStartMilli + oneDay;
  var date = new Date(dateMilli);
  event.value = util.printd("dd/mm/yy",date);
} else { event.value = "" }
```

**The issue is** if I input 05/04/15 in to the user field the result is 05/04/15 (same, wrong) while *any other date of the year* correctly increments by one day (ie 25/10/15 gives 26/10/15, 14/2/15 gives 15/2/15 etc)

The same error occurs on the 3rd of April 2016, 2nd of April 2017, etc (ie each year)

I have a fortnight (14) of these incrementing fields, each incrementing the date from the previous calculated field with the same javascript as above ("userField" is changed to date2, date3, date4 etc). **What is very strange** is that the next field that increments off the second of the two 05/04/15 correctly returns 06/04/15 and there isn't an issue after that.

Does anyone know why this might be?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That doesn't happen on my browser's JavaScript engine and/or in my locale, so it must be an Acrobat thing or that date may be special in your locale (e.g., DST).

In any case, that's not the correct way to add one day to a JavaScript date, not least because some days have more than that many milliseconds and some have less (transitioning to and from DST).

The correct way is to use `getDate` and `setDate`:

```
var strStart = this.getField("userField").value; 

if(strStart.length > 0) {
  var dateStart = util.scand("dd/mm/yy",strStart);
  dateStart.setDate(dateStart.getDate() + 1);     // Add one day
  event.value = util.printd("dd/mm/yy",dateStart);
} else { event.value = "" }
```

`setDate` is smart enough to handle it if you go past the end of the month (per specification).

If it's DST-related, the above will fix it. If it's some weird Acrobat thing, perhaps it will work around it. Either way, it's how this should be done.

Comment: Correct, it is caused by DST. That did not occur to me but it is of course the reason. I adapted my code from another time-adding function. Your method is far better, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Let me guess, that's the day daylight savings starts in your locale? 24 hours after midnight is not always the next day, because some days have 25 hours.

Approaches that come to my head:

- manipulate the day. (This is easy if Acrobat allows dates like the 32nd of January, because oyu can just increment the day. Otherwise, maybe don't bother because leap years aren't much better than DST.)
- don't start from midnight. If you never use the hour and minute within the day, don't pin your day at the strike of midnight, but at, say, 3am. After a change in DST status, later days in your fortnight might register as 2am or 4am, but as long as you're only using the day…